# How to move the mouse to an arbitrary point using Protractor/Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, point, mousemove

Is it possible to move the mouse to arbitrary coordinates on the screen/relative to an element in Protractor tests?  I see people recommend using Robot for Java users, but of course I can't use that in JavaScript.

Comment: If you downvote this will you please explain why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I figured it out for myself...just took some deep digging through Protractor and Selenium documentation.  Here is some example code:

```
  it('should pan plots when you click and drag', function() {
    var plot0 = element(by.css('.plot > canvas'));
    browser.actions()
      .mouseMove(plot0, {x: 100, y: 100}) // 100px from left, 100 px from top of plot0
      .mouseDown()
      .mouseMove({x: 400, y: 0}) // 400px to the right of current location
      .perform();
  });
```

Comment: this was very helpful for me just now. +1

Answer (score 4):

I also found a solution for simulating a swipe action.

```
var card = element(by.css('#card'));

browser.actions()
  .mouseMove(card, {x: 100, y: 100})
  .mouseDown()
  .mouseMove({x: 0, y: -400})
  .perform();

browser.sleep(500);

browser.actions()
  .mouseUp()
  .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var graphDimensions = {// see [1]
  Width: 0,
  Height: 0
};
company_page.company_Chart_Graph().getAttribute('width')
  .then(function(width) {
    graphDimensions.Width = parseInt(width);
  });

company_page.company_Chart_Graph().getAttribute('height').then(function(height) {
  graphDimensions.Height = parseInt(height);

  console.log('W' + graphDimensions.Width);
  console.log('H' + graphDimensions.Height);

  var plot0 = company_page.company_Chart_Graph();
  browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(plot0, {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    })
    .mouseDown()
    .mouseMove(plot0, {
      x: graphDimensions.Width,
      y: graphDimensions.Height
    })
    .mouseUp()
    .perform();

  browser.driver.sleep(23000);
  company_page.company_ReportDownload().click();
  browser.driver.sleep(23000);
});
```

[1]: http://testingalert.com/